# jQuery hide/show with non-zero duration not working in Firefox (but works in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, firefox, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

The basic jQuery hide / show code below does not seem to work in Firefox 29.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Unity desktop.  This exact same code works in Chrome 35.0.1916.114.

When selecting the "hide this div" link, FF seems to start the transition.  Inspecting using Firebug, the div attributes change from

```
<div id="togglediv" style="display: block;">
```

to

```
<div id="togglediv" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; 
 height: 88px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 1422px; opacity: 1;">
```

But nothing further. The transition to "display: none;" never happens.  No errors are throw to the Firebug console.

I've reviewed dozens of SO questions, but they seem to having some different issue related to no-duration hide().

If the duration is removed or changed to 0 the code works in both FF and Chrome.  Why would a non-zero duration break in FF?

**EDIT**: Change code below to use CDN version for easier testing.  Issue still remains.  Even after upgrading to latest 2.1.1 version.

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- <script src="/media/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>   -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #togglediv {
    background: #cccccc;
    }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body >
  <div style="display: block;" id="togglediv">
    <p>jQuery Test</p>
    <p><a id="hidelink" href="#">Hide this div</a></p>
  </div>
  <div id="bringback">
    <p><a id="showlink" href="#">Bring it back</a></p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    // Your code goes here.
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $( "#hidelink" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $( "#togglediv").hide( 500 );  // works in FF if 0 or blank
      });
      $( "#showlink" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $( "#togglediv").show( 500 );  // works in FF if 0 or blank
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT2**: FF 29.0 seems OK on ubuntu 12.04.4 under KDE Platform Version 4.8.5.  SO, it may be a Ubuntu Unity issue and not FF 29.0.

Comment: what does your console say in chrome?

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference between Firefox 29.0.1 and Chrome 35.0.1916.114 on Windows 8

Comment: @Viscocent: chrome console blank.  No issues.

Comment: @apaul34208: I also verified there is no issue with FF 29.0.1 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: try to upgrade your jQuery and then test it again, you can always revert back if its not the issue.

Comment: btw can i ask why do you have the ` event.preventDefault();` on your code?

Comment: @Viscocent: It is a style mentioned on the page http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Does it still fail if you replace ( 500 ) with ('slow')?

Comment: @sideroxylon: Slow fails also.

Comment: @ChrisFreeman there is no need for that since its not a link

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  After updating and restarting Ubuntu and Firefox the issue went away.  Argh!

Comment: @Viscocent: Do you mean that the preventDefault() is not needed since it not an "active" link?  I replaced the actual href URL with '#' for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Following advice from @Viscocent in comments above, I updated and restart Firefox and Ubuntu.  The problem has disappeared.  This question now needs to be resubmitted to the Journal of Non-Reproducible Results.  One lesson learned: restart Firefox often.